# Configuring PhpStorm with Moodle 1.9?

Tags: phpstorm, moodle

I've been trying to setup PhpStorm with Moodle 1.9 since few months but it was unsuccessful. I did go through [Moodle forums](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=253171) and other sites but failed to configure it.

I want to configure PhpStorm with moodle 1.9 so that it can help me with debugging and development.

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm -- official manuals and how-tos --- with pics and videos.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are here for phpstorm : https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_PhpStorm

Although Moodle 1.9 is old and unsupported. I would recommend upgrading to a later version of Moodle.

The route is to upgrade to the latest version of 1.9

- https://docs.moodle.org/19/en/Upgrading
- https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/MOODLE_19_STABLE

Then upgrade to Moodle 2.2

- https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Upgrading_to_Moodle_2.2
- https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/MOODLE_22_STABLE

Then choose a version of Moodle - 3.0 is the latest

- https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Upgrading
- https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/MOODLE_30_STABLE